# Saving Post Meta in Wordpress Admin Menu w/ Foreach Loop

Tags: php, wordpress

Here's the long and short:

I'm looking to add a global controller for post meta tags in Wordpress. I already have an established Wordpress custom admin page within our theme. I also already have added meta boxes to individual pages which store key value pairs in a more polished fashion. I have been able to call all key value pairs in a foreach loop so that they display in the administrative page. I'm having difficulty getting the input from these values on the admin panel page to properly update when the submit_button(); is clicked. I've gotten the update_post_meta function to outright erase the previous values but I have not been able to get the update_post_meta function to properly pass the $_POST value into the value at the database.

I know that the following code is not working as it's halfway through two attempts. Any help is appreciated:

```
 $pages = get_pages(); 
      foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
        $post_id = $page->ID;
        $meta = get_post_meta($post_id);
        /* $value1 = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'value1', true );
        $value2 = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'value2', true ); */

        echo '<h3>' . $page->post_title . '</h3>';
        echo '<label for="options_value1_' . $post_id . '">Value 1:</label>';
        echo '<input type="text" id="options_value1_' . $post_id . '" name="options_value1" value="' . $meta['value1'][0] . '" size="25" /><br />';
        echo '<label for="options_value2_' . $post_id . '">Value 2:</label>';
        echo '<input type="text" id="options_value2_' . $post_id . '" name="options_value2" value="' . $meta['value2'][0] . '" size="25" /><hr />';

        }

        foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'value1', $_POST('value1');
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'value2', $_POST('value2');
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:
$post_id is defined in the first loop, but not in the second loop.
Also you have a syntax error in the second loop. You're not closing the parenthesis of update_post_meta() and you're not using braces for $_POST. It should be $_POST[], not $_POST().
Also, the POST parameter you're looking for is options_value1 and options_value 2, because those are the names of the fields from the first loop.

Second loop should go like this:

```
foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
$post_id = $page->ID;
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'value1', $_POST['options_value1']);
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'value2', $_POST['options_value2']);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This logic appears right. I did try something similar to this previously but I'm still running into this issue here:

Notice: Undefined index: options_value1 in /FILEPATH/ on line 234

Is this an issue in passing the $_POST value from the first input field or am I misunderstanding something beyond this? I appreciate your help.

Comment: For some reason options_value1 is not being passed. To avoid getting the error when $_POST['options_value1'] is empty, insert this code before update_post_meta function: if(isset($_POST['options_value1'])) { update_post_meta(...); update_post_meta(...); }. To make the $_POST pass the value, you need to have a form with method="post" to pass the data.

Comment: This worked. Needed some basic changes to fit the specific application, but this was my hiccup. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: One more quick follow up - I apologize for being super ignorant when it comes to getting $_POST to play nice with Wordpress. The variables are all passing properly, but on page reload they do not show as updated until I reload the page again. I'm assuming that I'm just processing something improperly here on a form action or similar.

Comment: You should make something like this in HTML: <form method="post" action="http://example.com?action=update"> and in PHP: if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'update') { $option1 = $_POST['options_value1']; $option2 = $_POST['options_value2']; update_post_meta(...); update_post_meta(...); }. I'm saying this because you're probably executing it all on the same page load, so you have to reload the page once to send the post request and the second time you reload it, the post data is received. I hope this helps, I'm really tired so I might be wrong.